# how to perform multiple selection in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am a beginner to objective c.Please tell me that how perform multiplay selection in NSTableView.I am unable to retain previous selection, when i am clicking on another row.

Comment: It might help you to make an attempt yourself, find out where you get stuck, and provide us with more details and some sample code.

Comment: actually i need to select multiple rows programmatically according to checkbox state. i am unable to find out the way to show selection in nstableview programmaticaly.

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable multiple selection on the table view by calling:

`[tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection: YES]`

You can then select multiple rows by pressing Command+Click on the rows you want.

Comment: but i need to select those rows when checkbox is get checked.actually i need to do selection through coding.

Answer (score 3):

The method call you are looking for is

```
- (void)selectRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes byExtendingSelection:(BOOL)extend
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you would have got the answer, 
but the better way is, when you click the check box, you could select the row by using api selectRowIndex and once you want to process, you could get all the selectedItemindexes,